# tf.print doesn't print with sess on node being evaluated

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using tf [print documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print)

I wrote

```
    print_op = tf.print("tensors:", cut_points[0,0,:], output_stream=sys.stderr)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        return cut_points
```

But not output to std whatsoever (I see other logs, and the session is indeed evaluates this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) only affects **new** operations created within the context. In you snippet, you are not creating any new operation in the context, so it is having no effect. The simplest solution is to use a [`tf.identity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity) operation that will produce the same result but will have the control dependencies:

```
print_op = tf.print("tensors:", cut_points[0,0,:], output_stream=sys.stderr)
with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
    return tf.identity(cut_points)
```